# Use DB::raw() with Table prefix

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I would to make a SUM in query with `Laravel 5` Query Builder.

```
return DB::table('table1')->join('table2','table1.id','=','table2.id')
            ->where('table1.user_id','=',$userId)
            ->whereMonth('table2.date', '=', $month )
            ->whereYear('table2.date', '=', $year )->select('table2.*', DB::raw('SUM(table1.count) AS count_single'))->groupby('table2.id')->get();
```

but my problem is that I have a prefix table (xc_), and DB::raw return error

```
"Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'table1.count' "
```

It is a problem with prefix table, because if I put:

```
$table_prefix = env('DB_TABLE_PREFIX', 'xc_');
DB::raw('SUM('.$table_prefix.'table1.count) AS count_single')
```

It work, so the problem is prefix, but I don't like this method, and so:
there is a method for use DB::Raw without specifying prefix table?

Comment: Is that table prefix available for all tables?

Comment: if all tables in your database has prefix then..
[Check this link it can help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885681/laravel-migrations-table-prefix-issue#16261409)

Comment: Yes, prefix is in all table, and I have already set in database.php the correct prefix

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `DB::raw()` is use to create a *raw expression*, so you have to use full
>   table name.

Laravel Query Builder has an inbuilt function for getting table prefix **`DB::getTablePrefix()`**

Replace the above code with this and it will work.

```
return DB::table('table1')
                ->join('table2', 'table1.id', '=', 'table2.id')
                ->where('table1.user_id', '=', $userId)
                ->whereMonth('table2.date', '=', $month)
                ->whereYear('table2.date', '=', $year)
                ->select('table2.*', DB::raw('SUM(' . DB::getTablePrefix() . 'table1.count) AS count_single'))
                ->groupby('table2.id')
                ->get();
```

---

Reference:

- [Illuminate/Database/Connection](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html#method_getTablePrefix)

Comment: ok, so I have to put prefix! perfect and thank's for explanation!